# How did Wechat for Android locate the most recently generated image automatically?

Tags: android, image, screenshot, wechat

I've noticed that when I take a screenshot of my Android phone using hard key combinations, if I enter the **Wechat** application shortly after the screenshot is successfully taken and trying to send a picture to one of my friends the Wechat application will automatically popup a preview of the recently taken screenshot.

I found this quite convenient for I don't need to enter into the image selector to select the image(it's most likely that if I've taken a screenshot and then enter the **Wechat's** image sending page shortly after this, it's highly possible that this screenshot is what I want to send to others).

The question is, how did **Wechat** for Android managed to do this? Or I want to know if it's possible to locate the recently generated images in Android automatically with code, is there any APIs I can use?

**Notice:** For those who haven't heard of **Wechat**, it's a instant message application from China that is similar to **Viber/WhatsApp/Kik**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about when you take a picture, like a screenshot, and then its automatically put above the "submit" button in the chat, then I think that they simply take the latest picture of your corresponding folder according to the date.

If the last modification time is close enough then they probably suggest it in the chat.

Comment: Yes, I think you got the point, normally the screenshot taken by combination of hard keys will be saved to a target directory in the SDCard, Wechat must have monitor this directory constantly. Thanks.

Comment: An other way would has been to use a listener for the camera but it seems definitely too complicated compared to the first solution.

Comment: I've made an experiment, you are right, they are monitoring the directory.

Comment: Glad to having help then :)